# Attributed text with TextView causing a crash

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring, swift4.1

I have following swift code for generating an attributed string,

```
func getAttributedTermsAndServicesText() -> NSAttributedString {
    let text = StringConstants.RegisterConstants.termsOfUseLabelText
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    let termsRange = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: StringConstants.CommonConstants.termsOfUse)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: WebViewLinkType.termsOfUse.getLink(), range: termsRange)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: termsRange)

    let privacyRange = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: StringConstants.CommonConstants.privacyStatement)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.link, value: WebViewLinkType.privacyStatement.getLink(), range: privacyRange)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: privacyRange)

    print(attributedString.mutableString)
    return attributedString
  }
```

This method returns generated attributed string. But crashes on this line of code

```
//Generate attributed string
let attributedString = getAttributedTermsAndServicesText()

//crash after this line
cell.textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

It prints following details in console,

> -[__NSCFNumber _isDefaultFace]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d0d9c0 (
>       "4   libc++abi.dylib                     0x1ca0798f  + 78",
>       "5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x1ca07493 __cxa_rethrow + 90",
>       "6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x1ca131ab objc_exception_rethrow + 42",
>       "7   CoreFoundation                      0x1d699231 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600",
>       "8   CoreFoundation                      0x1d698fd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104" ) 2018-06-06 02:52:07.439226-0700
>   MyApp[370:63347] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber _isDefaultFace]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d0d9c0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1d78bb3d 0x1ca13067 0x1d790fd1 0x1d78f0c3 0x1d6b7dc8 0x2292fe93 0x2292f727 0x2294bf4f 0x2294bc43
>   0x22a66523 0x1cc728 0x1c42c0 0x1cd0f0 0x22cebc13 0x22cebde5 0x22cd9d79
>   0x22cf08db 0x22a9cf0f 0x229bb483 0x20613cb7 0x20607d77 0x20607c05
>   0x20596839 0x205b4fdb 0x205248e3 0x1f9c31bf 0x1d9dca7f 0x1d734c19
>   0x1d74865f 0x1d747ebd 0x1d745eab 0x1d6991af 0x1d698fd1 0x1ee43b41
>   0x22a21a53 0x28d578 0x1ce864eb) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

But still, I'm not able to get exact reason for this crash.
Has anyone faced this kind of issue before?

Comment: `NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue` That's not the kind of value you want. You are setting a `Int` (encapulated in a `(NS)Number`) instead of providing a `UIFont`. I think that you put the wrong `NSAttributedStringKey`.

Comment: This code was in swift 2 initially, and recently I converted that code to compile with swift 4.1 using Xcode Automatic conversion

Comment: Change the .font to .understyle for the second one: `attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: termsRange)` => `attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: termsRange)`
 Else it doesn’t make sense. Also, be certain that `.getLink()` returns correctly a `UIFont`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Larme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please add font name and size

```
func getAttributedTermsAndServicesText() -> NSAttributedString {
    let text = StringConstants.RegisterConstants.termsOfUseLabelText
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    let termsRange = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: StringConstants.CommonConstants.termsOfUse)

    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.link, value: WebViewLinkType.termsOfUse.getLink(), range: termsRange)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: termsRange)

    let privacyRange = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: StringConstants.CommonConstants.privacyStatement)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.link, value: WebViewLinkType.privacyStatement.getLink(), range: privacyRange)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: privacyRange)

    print(attributedString.mutableString)
    return attributedString
  }
```

Comment: Why use `NSFontAttributeName` and `NSAttributedStringKey.font` at the same time? That's strange.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts and suggestions. From both suggestions, I made my answer.